# TS errors online exactly ( Jhipster 6.7.0 )

Tags: jhipster

When I create my application for production with the new version of Jhipster, it no longer tells me the exact line of error in my file:

The error is given to me in this step:

```
npm run webpack:prod
```

```
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3972): Object is possibly 'null'.
src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3677): Object is possibly 'null'.
src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3833): Object is possibly 'null'.
```

The errors tell me well, but the lines (3972,3677,3833), do not correspond to those in my file. And not only for this specific case, but for all who will come out during development, I need to know the exact line in my file.

How can I do to detect errors in the exact line of my files?

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"
(node:9047) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Hash: 8de665ac5fd05610ed73
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 4521ms
Built at: 2020-02-11 19:03:53
 6 assets
Entrypoint polyfills = app/polyfills.8de665ac5fd05610ed73.bundle.js
Entrypoint global = content/global.b97cbe1779ef2c8c2587.css app/global.8de665ac5fd05610ed73.bundle.js
Entrypoint main = app/main.8de665ac5fd05610ed73.bundle.js
[0] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
    factory:2344ms building:1835ms = 4179ms
[1] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss 39 bytes {0} [built]
    factory:2252ms building:414ms = 2666ms
[2] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 0 bytes {1} [built]
    factory:2344ms building:1836ms = 4180ms
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3972): Object is possibly 'null'.
src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3677): Object is possibly 'null'.
src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.html(1,3833): Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Comment: Have you tried building with the dev profile instead of prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going piece by piece it was this:

// AFTER

```
*ngIf="editForm.get('root').value == false"
```

// NOW

```
*ngIf="editForm.get('root')?.value == false"
```

It is necessary to add "?" since at the time of packaging for PRO it will fail, but it does not tell you the line well, since the error occurs after minifying for PRO

Comment: Can you please add your `.yo-rc.json` to the original question description? That way, we can try to reproduce this issue and fix it for the next release.